# Find Where string contains keywords

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, keyword, contain

User inputs some keywords that he wants to get a notification, when a new post title contains these. Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
LOCATE( LOWER( REPLACE(  `app_notif_keywords` ,  ' ',  ',' ) ) , LOWER( REPLACE(  'Visiska tamsa | Pitch Black (2000)',  ' ',  ',' ) ) ) !=0
```

Here is a stripped down version:

```
LOCATE('the,gift,pitch,black', 'visiska,tamsa,|,pitch,black,(2000)')
```

However, I'm getting nothing returned. What can I use instead to make it work?

Comment: Full text index.  That would be the appropriate technology for this type of problem.

Comment: I think I'm just using a wrong sql function, is there any function to check whether both arrays have any same value containing? E.g. 1,2,3 and 4,5,6 don't have same values, but 1,2,3 and 5,3,4 has.

Comment: Which db are you using? mysql, oracle, sql server, postgres, etc?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm using mysql

Answer (score 1):

To match any of a range of csv values, use `regexp` like this:

```
select * from mytable
where lower(concat(',', app_notif_keywords, ','))
  regexp lower(concat(',(', replace('Visiska tamsa Pitch Black', ' ', '|'), '),'))
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ff16/1)